# How to describe nested request body in OpenAPI (Swagger) syntax?

Tags: api, swagger, documentation, openapi, swagger-3.0

I need to describe REST (json) api with OpenAPI (Swagger) syntax. I have stuck at the point when **I need to describe nested request body**. Please suggest how to make it, lets use as example the next nested request body:

```
{
   "pauses" : [
     {"name" : "PAUSING_AUTO"},
     {"name" : "NO_PAUSE_CRITERIA","Min" : 15},
     {"name" : "PREVENTED_PAUSE","Min" : 5},
     {"name" : "REVERT_TO_RUN"},
     {"name" : "RUNNING"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following description would do:

```yaml
pauses:
    type: "array"
    items:
      type: "object"
      required: 
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          type: "string"
        Min:
          type: "integer"
```